# display at single function

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my condition,

```
counter = 0;
if(count == 0) {
        [testArray addObject:imageArray[counter]];
        [testArray addObject:imageArray[counter +1]];
    }
    if(count == 1) {
        [testArray addObject:imageArray[counter+2]];
        [testArray addObject:imageArray[counter+3]];
    }
    if(count == 2) {
        [testArray addObject:imageArray[counter+4]];
        [testArray addObject:imageArray[counter+5]];
    }
    if(count == 3) {
        [testArray addObject:imageArray[counter+6]];
        [testArray addObject:imageArray[counter+7]];
    }
    if(count == 4) {
        [testArray addObject:imageArray[counter+8]];
        [testArray addObject:imageArray[counter+9]];
    }
```

i want to minimize this script using for loop.  how to write a single for loop.

Comment: Surely you can see a pattern there...

Comment: `count * 2` and `count * 2 + 1` obiously

Comment: sorry the count and counter inside array both are different

Comment: He want to minimize THIS script USING for loop. Why all the answers with loop? :)

Comment: each count has two images if i click button two images to save on NSDocumentDirectory and count=1 and button press then to save two images and so on.

Comment: if i used for loop it saved all ten images to Document.  What to do now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int count=0; count<n; count++)
{

   [testArray addObject:imageArray[count*2]];
   [testArray addObject:imageArray[count*2+1]];

}
```

Comment: each count has two images if i click button two images to save on NSDocumentDirectory and count=1 and button press then to save two images and so on

Comment: if i used for loop it saved all ten images to Document. What to do now

Comment: exactly what you want to do , i didn't get plz explain.

Comment: i want this if count = 0, i click the button to save two images on document folder  and count =1, then save two images on document folder and so on. The above if condition is perfectly working for my requirement, but i had count upto 75 i.e.., (count = 0 to 75) the line of script increasing……

Comment: then create one counter and increase that up to your button then put that imagearray[counter*2] and iamgearray[counter*2+1] simple

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

```
for(int i=0; i<=count; i++){
    [testArray addObject:imageArray[i*2]];
    [testArray addObject:imageArray[i*2+1]];
}
```

Better:

```
for(int i=0; i<=count*2+1; i++){
    [testArray addObject:imageArray[i]];
}
```

Better (depending on what you want to achieve):

```
[testArray addObjectsFromArray:imageArray];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean

```
[testArray addObject:imageArray[count *2]];
[testArray addObject:imageArray[(count *2) + 1]];
```

Hope this helps